# GRASS "Projection of dataset does not appear to match current location" Error

Tags: coordinate-system, grass-gis

I tried to import a virtual raster (that's possible right?) into GRASS v. 7.4.0 loaded as a plugin of QGIS v. 2.18.18. It gave me this error however. I know the rasters in the VR are NAD83 (I checked the metadata to be certain), and my location/ mapset is also NAD83 (I double checked this as well), so why is there a projection error? I didn't get this error when I loaded the rasters individually either

g.proj gave me:

C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/grass/GRASS-~1.0/bin/g.proj.exe -p
-PROJ_INFO-------------------------------------------------

name       : GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980)

ellps      : grs80

proj       : ll

towgs84    : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0

no_defs    : defined

-PROJ_UNITS------------------------------------------------

unit       : degree

units      : degrees

meters     : 1.0

Successfully finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (triple) check the projection of the virtual raster with `gdalinfo`, and the GRASS location setting with `g.proj -p`

If you're sure they are equivalent, then just use the "Override projection check" option when importing. It appears when you click on the "Show advanced options" button.

Comment: Not sure how to interpret this output it gave me, but I just created this mapset and specifically set it NAD83, so it would be impossible for it to be anything else? I'm going to put the output in the original question so the formatting's better

Comment: I don't know what the deal with the error was, but "override projection check" seems to have fixed it